# Firefox extension development - managing tabs

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon

I'm creating an extension to make finding tabs easier, and part of that involves comparing a search term to the titles of the tabs currently open. At the moment, I'm fairly sure I can figure out how to compare the term to the tab titles, but I can't convert the tab I end up with to a variable so that I can manipulate it. Help please?

Code:

```
    if (tabQuery == tabs.title){ 
           tab = tabs.activeTab
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`tabs` has no text property.  Also, the `activeTab` property is read-only. Try instead:

```
var tabs = require('tabs');


for each (var tab in tabs)
 if (tabQuery == tab.title) {
  tab.activate();
  break;
 }
```